# How can I detect whether a browser window is focused or not?

Tags: javascript

My page should make notification sounds only when the window is in the background.  I can track the `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur` events to notice when the focus state changes.  However, I don't know whether the window will load focused or not, since it might load in a background tab, for instance.

How do I decide whether to play sounds or not before I get an `onfocus`/`onblur` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just assume it's loaded blurred, and then change the status to focused as soon as you receive any type of event (keydown/mousemove)?

Comment: That's a good idea.  It's not a perfect solution, but it might be the best thing that will work.

Comment: `mousemove` is triggered even if you move your mouse on a blurred window, use `mousedown` instead. Try it here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/mousemove.html

Answer (score 0):

The onfocus event should be triggered when the page is initially opened (in the foreground). At least it is in FF3/IE8.

So you could have sounds on initially, turn them off when onfocus is triggered, and turn them back on when onblur is triggered.

Comment: Even when someone does an open-to-new-tab with the switch-to-new-tab preference off?  (Not saying it doesn't, asking because I want to know. :)

Comment: For me, when I opened in a new tab (in the background), onfocus was not triggered. Once I switched to the tab, it triggered. 

So if you start with sounds on, that should work, right? If the tab is opened in the foreground, sounds will be on, but the onfocus event will turn them off immediately. If the tab is opened in the background, sound stay on until you switch to that tab.

Comment: I see that in FF3, but not in Safari.  Safari doesn't give me an onfocus until the window actually gains focus after being in the background.