# how to stop setInterval auto-refresh when page/tab is inactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

i have a javascript to parse twitter feeds and show them in a block in my page every 30 seconds, the code is something like this:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
    {
        //get twitter feeds
    });
}, 30000);
```

now in case the user minimized his browser or switched to another tab (page is not active) i want to disable this auto_referesh `clearInterval(auto_refresh);`

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer:

[Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out

- [How can I detect whether a browser window is focused or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831686/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-browser-window-is-focused-or-not)
- [Determine whether webpage has foreground window focus/is active tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268298/determine-whether-webpage-has-foreground-window-focus-is-active-tab)
- [How to tell if browser/tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)
- [Is it possible to tell if a user has my page minimized or the inactive tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847108/is-it-possible-to-tell-if-a-user-has-my-page-minimized-or-the-inactive-tab)
- [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)
- https://odondo.wordpress.com/2007/08/28/javascript-and-cross-browser-window-focus/

Also note that Chrome apparently has some optimizations that slow down the firing of the timer when the tab is not in focus: [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

This answere is pretty clean : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677784/9027171

An excerpt from the answer of    [infinito84](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2661609/infinito84)

```
 if(!document.hasFocus()){
       // The tab is not active
 }
    else{
       // The tab is active
 }
```